# Function becomes undefined when declaring local variable with same name

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have declared a function in file so that it becomes global:

```js
function speakService() {

    var speakService = {};

    var speak = function(word) {
        console.log(word);
    };

    speakService.speak = speak;

    return speakService;
}
```

Using AngularJS, I want to add this service as dependency:

```js
angular
    .module('login', ['ngRoute'])
    .factory('speakService', [function() {
        var speakService = speakService();
        return speakService;
    }]);
```

But as soon as the interpreter hits the line:

```js
var speakService = speakService();
```

the speakService()-function is undefined. If I change the speakService variable to speakSvc like this it works fine:

```js
var speakSvc = speakService();
```

Can somebody explain why my global function is undefined when declaring a local variable with the same name?

Regards!

Comment: You don't need to create a named variable inside your `speakService` function. Just return an object literal with an assigned speak function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the variable appears to be undefined is [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). When you write something like `var x = 3` the definition of `x` is hoisted to the top of the current scope (functional in this case since you are using `var`). The assignment itself happens when you hit that particular line.

So in your specific case, when you enter the scope of that variable you define it `var speakService` first, which hides the function `speakService` from the rest of the scope. Then you try to execute the line `speakService = speakService()` and since `speakService` is just an uninitialized variable you get undefined.

Comment: Indeed, the declaration of a variable with the same name hides the global variable. The global variable is still available, e.g. by refencing it using the windows object. I just tested this out. I am not sure what hoisting has to do with this. Even without moving the variable declaration to the top of the function the global variable would be hidden - or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of javascript's [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

```
function() {
        var spkService = speakService();
        return spkService;
    }
```

Will be same as

```
function() {
        var spkService; //Declaration moved to top
        spkService= speakService(); //here spkService is undefined
        return spkService;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, your issue is hoisting. Just return an object literal and use the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) pattern.

```js
var myService = (function speakService() {
    var speak = function(word) {
        console.log(word);
    };
  
    return {
      speak: speak
    };
})();

myService.speak("TEST");
```