# Why do I get NaN after I run my function?

Tags: javascript

I watch a video where some man does the same thing and it works.

```js
var beer = 2.50;
var hot_dog = 2.75;
var pop = 3.00;
var cash = 15.00;

function hot_dog() {
  cash = cash - hot_dog;
  console.log(cash)
}
hot_dog();
```

Comment: Your code does not run. `Uncaught TypeError: hot_dog is not a function`

Comment: You have declared a variable and a function with the same name: *hot_dog*. Only one can exist. Since function declarations are processed before variable declarations (and before any code is executed), the variable declaration wins due to the assignment `hot_dog = 2.75`.

Comment: Why do you have a float variable and a function both called hot_dog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function becomes undefined when declaring local variable with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554209/function-becomes-undefined-when-declaring-local-variable-with-same-name) (See accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable named `hot_dog` and tried to name a `function` `hot_dog` as well. You can't have it both ways. Use separate names and your code should work, e.g.:

```
var beer = 2.50;
var hot_dog = 2.75;

var pop = 3.00;

var cash = 15.00;

function hot_dog_func() {
  cash = cash - hot_dog;
  console.log(cash)
}
hot_dog_func();
cash = cash - pop;
console.log(cash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables and functions must be unique in terms of names. `hot_dog` is a variable. It's also declared as a function.

You can re-frame this by making the function *describe what it does* instead of giving it a random name:

```
var beer = 2.50;
var hot_dog = 2.75;

var pop = 3.00;

var cash = 15.00;

function buy(item_cost) {
  cash = cash - item_cost;
  console.log(cash)
}

buy(hot_dog);
cash = cash - pop;
console.log(cash)
```

In actual JavaScript code you might want to make a `class` that defines a cash balance and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post: [What happens when JavaScript variable name and function name is the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675821/what-happens-when-javascript-variable-name-and-function-name-is-the-same)

When you are using hot_dog variable in the subtract operation which is not a number, thus anything subtracted from NaN is NaN